# SKStoreProductViewController Animation and UI

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

Is it possible to change the way SKStoreProductViewController comes out and looks like?

like in full screen instead of half sheet, coming out from left to right instead of popping up?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't. `SKStoreProductViewController` **ignores** changes to `modalPresentationStyle`, according to the Apple's developer documentation.

checkout this [apple developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstoreproductviewcontroller).

> This class ignores modalPresentationStyle settings, and those settings
> have no impact on the sheet's presentation.